# How to access child properties of MainForm.ui.qml from main.qml in Qt 5.5?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using signals and slots in c++ to read the contents of a selected directory and output to a TextArea in MainForm.ui.qml. I know I have everything working because the signal is sending the correct string to the function "setTextArea1" in main.qml which I can output to console.log- however I can't seem to find the correct syntax to send that string to id:TextArea1 in MainForm.ui.qml.
I keep getting

```
'textArea1 is not defined'
```

I'm sure it's simple but I can't seem to find any examples...(I rebuilt the program using a single qml file and it worked but I really want to find out how to make it work with MainForm.ui.qml)

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

signal qmlSelectClicked(string text)

function setTextArea1(text) {
    console.log(text);
    textArea1.text = text
}


menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&Open")
            onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}

MainForm {
    anchors.fill: parent
    selectButton.onClicked: qmlSelectClicked("Select Clicked")
}
}
```

MainForm.ui.qml

```
Item {
width: 640
height: 480

property alias printButton: printButton
property alias selectButton: selectButton
property alias textArea1: textArea1

TextArea {
    id: textArea1
    x: 41
    y: 20
    width: 558
    height: 359
    text: "Select a Directory to scan..."
}

RowLayout {
    x: 367
    y: 379
    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 196
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 163
    anchors.centerIn: parent


    Button {
        id: selectButton
        text: qsTr("Select")
    }
    Button {
        id: printButton
        text: qsTr("Print To File")
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current scope that you're in doesn't know anything about a `textArea1`, as evidenced by the error message. You need to give an `id` to the `MainForm`:

```
MainForm {
    id: mainForm
    anchors.fill: parent
    selectButton.onClicked: qmlSelectClicked("Select Clicked")
}
```

Then qualify the access to `textArea1` with it:

```
mainForm.textArea1.text = text
```